# Clarification on confusing news headline: Trump says spoke 'sarcastically' about injecting disinfectants

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I encountered this headline in a news website just now:

"Trump says spoke 'sarcastically' about injecting disinfectants"

English is not my first language but I know there is something wrong with the phrase. It got me reading the headline many times to figure it out, and the most logical 'fix' I could think of is to add 'he' before the word spoke.

With that, is it really valid to omit the 'he' in this example, considering how much it resulted confusion?

Answer (score 1):

Headlines are made as short as possible so that the largest possible type can be used, whether on a printed page or on an HTML page. They are made with native English speakers in mind, not learners, but even so, they are sometimes incomprehensible even to fully-qualified speakers. You can say it's not valid, but nothing can be done about it except to laugh, and to look at the full article to see what was meant.

Comment: I don't think news articles in English are "made with native English speakers in mind". I realized the original article is from a French news website. Similar news written in US/UK does have the "he". For example:   (1) "Trump claims he spoke 'sarcastically' when repeatedly ..." (2) "Coronavirus | U.S. President Donald Trump says he spoke ..."   That title is unacceptable and shouldn't be normalized.

Comment: Very well, then, I authorize you to take them to the woodshed.But, your question being from four months ago, you may have to remind them why they are being spanked.